# Нужна ли запятая перед "как только"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы

> Но как только стемнело, он услышал глухое рыканье зверя...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Возможны оба варианта: с запятой и без неё.

В отрыве от контекста первое простое предложение читается без паузы между НО и КАК ТОЛЬКО. Я не стал бы ставить запятую. Предыдущий текст, возможно, внёс бы коррективы в интонацию и пунктуацию. Вот что говорит Грамота.ру.

[**Вопрос № 285932**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%83%D1%8E&start=375)

> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> Д. Э. Розенталь в справочнике «Пунктуация» указывает, что запятая между союзом ***но***, стоящим в начале предложения, и следующим за ним подчинительным союзом не ставится при отсутствии паузы между союзами и ставится, если пауза делается. Таким образом, здесь окончательное решение принимает автор текста.

Answer (score 3):

[Л. Успенский, В. Успенский. Мифы Древней Греции](https://books.google.ee/books?id=2CzKDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT242&lpg=PT242&dq=%D0%9D%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE,%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%20%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8F&source=bl&ots=CBDpN8S84_&sig=ACfU3U2YqNUUarbXft3KTzwWU9stcEybgw&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjX4-fEu9DsAhUh_CoKHSQ9DogQ6AEwAXoECAgQAg#v=onepage&q=%D0%9D%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%2C%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%20%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8F&f=false):

> Между тем наступила ночь. Геракл зажёг костёр, чтобы зверь не напал на него в темноте. **Но как только** стемнело, он услышал глухое рыканье зверя, кружившего во мраке недалеко от костра.

Союз **но** в этом предложении является присоединительным, после него следует [подчинительный союз](https://classes.ru/all-russian/dictionary-ortho-term-29263.htm) **как только**. Я думаю, что в этом контексте пунктуация правильная и запятая не нужна — союзы по смыслу **тесно связаны** между собой, пауза между ними отсутствует.

Ставить запятую между союзами или не ставить — это очень часто решает сам автор (я выбрала самых известных; см. в [Нацкорпусе](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&startyear=1800&text=lexform&req=%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE&api=1.0&mode=main&env=alpha&endyear=2019&nodia=1&p=1)).

**С запятой:**
Но, как только он на секунду прервал процедуру, чтобы перевести дыхание, профессор встал, вынул из кармана платок, вытер лицо и отставил стул, показывая, что процедура окончена. [Анатолий Рыбаков. Тяжелый песок (1975-1977)]
Но, как только добирались люди до этого места, всё исчезало, одни лишь голые скалы мрачно сторожили его. [И. А. Ефремов. Озеро горных духов (1942-1943)]

**Без запятой:**
Но как только поезд убрал хвост, бабы дружной кучкой все вместе уверенно подались деревянным переходом через рельсы и куда-то правее леса. [Александр Солженицын. В круге первом, т.1, гл. 26-51 (1968) // «Новый Мир», 1990]
Но как только увидишь человека с важным и тихим лицом в старинном костюме, прикладывающего к сердцу пистолет, громко скажи ему: «Подожди, Рауссон, есть слово и для тебя». [А. С. Грин. Ива (1923)]